# Botão em javascript que altera a imagem

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer um site que contenha uma imagem e um botão. Quando o botão for apertado a imagem deve se alterar.

Fiz um código, mas ele não dá certo. Procurei por tudo e não achei a resposta para minha pergunta.

Segue o código:

```js
function alterarImagem(img, flor.jpeg){
  document.getElementById("img").src = flor.jpeg; 
}
```

```css
*{margin: 0 auto; padding:0;}

body{
    background-color:black;
}

#dvCentro{
    width:200px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: white;
    border:5px solid #821919;
    padding:6px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>exercicio 5</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dvCentro">
      <button onclick="alterarImagem('img', 'flor.jpeg');">
        Clique para trocar a imagem
      </button>
      <br />
      <div style="border-bottom:3px solid #000; padding:5px;"></div>
      <br />
      <img src="pqp.jpeg" alt="Imagem" title="Imagem" id="img" boarder="0px" width="200px" height="200px"/>
      <br />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro precisa entender que, ao passar parâmetros para uma `function`, no seu caso a function `alterarImagem`, os parametros devem ser nomes de variávies válidos, e "flor.jpeg" não é um nome válido (sugiro estudar [nomes de variáveis](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guia/Valores,_Vari%C3%A1veis_e_Literais) em javascript), deveria ser algo como:

```
function alterarImagem(img, nomeImagem) { 
    document.getElementById(img).src = nomeImagem;
}
```

Assim, no evento click ao executar `alterarImagem('img', 'flor.jpeg');` a function vai receber os valores corretos nas variávies "img" e "nomeImagem"